# Inaccurate hover behavior with KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am using Kivy and KivyMD and running into an issue when combining a Kivy RecycleView with a KivyMD HoverBehavior. What happens is that the bottom element in my list (inside the recycle view) behaves the way I expect it to with the hover behavior, correctly detecting when the mouse enters and exits the bounding box of the list element. However, as I move up higher on the list, the element that is being detected as hovered gets further and further from where my mouse pointer actually is.

For example, when hovering over element 10 of 10, the on_enter and on_leave methods of the hover behavior correctly show that, but I would have to hover over element 8 to get element 9 to be detected, 6 to get 8 to be detected, and so on.

Here is the code I have so far, pared down as far as I can to be able to reproduce the issue. You can install the dependencies (Kivy and KivyMD) and run the code. From there, just try to hover over various elements in the list and notice how the wrong checkboxes appear checked and the wrong element numbers output to the console.

What might be causing this type of behavior?

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, StringProperty
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import HoverBehavior
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'TestItem'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'

<TestItem>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .8, .8, .8, 1
        Line:
            points: 0,0,self.width,0
            width:1 
    CheckBox:
        id: "checkbox"
        active: True if root.status == 'completed' else False
    Label:
        size_hint_x: .86
        text: root.title
''')

class TestItem(RecycleDataViewBehavior, RelativeLayout, HoverBehavior):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    status = StringProperty()
    title = StringProperty()

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.children[1].background_checkbox_normal ="atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/checkbox_on"
        print("Entering", self.title)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.children[1].background_checkbox_normal ="atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/checkbox_off"
        print("Leaving", self.title)

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'title': str(x), 'status': "not started"} for x in range(10)]
        self.refresh_from_data()

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HoverBehavior` does not appear to work correctly for `RelayiveLayout`. Try changing

```
class TestItem(RecycleDataViewBehavior, RelativeLayout, HoverBehavior):
```

to

```
class TestItem(RecycleDataViewBehavior, HoverBehavior, FloatLayout):
```

That will also require refactoring the `<TestItem>` rule in your `kv`. Something like:

```
<TestItem>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .8, .8, .8, 1
        Line:
            points: self.x, self.y,self.width,self.y
            width:1 
    CheckBox:
        id: "checkbox"
        size_hint_x: .14
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.86}
        center_y: root.center_y
        active: True if root.status == 'completed' else False
    Label:
        size_hint_x: .86
        pos_hint: {'x': 0}
        center_y: root.center_y
        text: root.title
```

Comment: That does solve the problem for me! Wonder why the relative layout behaves so strangely with the hover behavior.Thanks for your help!